# Adding subview to CollectionViewCell just once (cell reuseability issues)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to add a simple gradient at the bottom of each cell. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` I have the code:

```
CAGradientLayer *bottomFade = [CAGradientLayer layer];
bottomFade.name = @"Gradient";
bottomFade.frame = CGRectMake(0, cell.background.frame.size.height*0.8, cell.background.frame.size.width, cell.background.frame.size.height*0.2);
bottomFade.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
bottomFade.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
bottomFade.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2f] CGColor], nil];

[cell.background.layer addSublayer:bottomFade];
```

The problem is that when the cell is being scrolled, the sublayer is added over and over again, which obviously is not a desired effect.

I know how to handle reuseability issues when it comes to the `UITableView`, but what should I do when it comes to working with the `UICollectionView`?

I tried to set a custom cell property `isConfigured`, but when I checked for it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` the result was that only two cells were generated, and then they were repeating (honestly, I have absolutely no idea why).

What would you suggest to handle such a problem? Perhaps it would be better to add some custom code in the cell's subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code that only requires once inside 'awakeFromNib' so it won't be called twice or thrice on its life cycle

which would appear like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    CAGradientLayer *bottomFade = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    bottomFade.name = @"Gradient";
    bottomFade.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.background.frame.size.height*0.8, self.background.frame.size.width, self.background.frame.size.height*0.2);
    bottomFade.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    bottomFade.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
    bottomFade.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2f] CGColor], nil];

    [self.background.layer addSublayer:bottomFade];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved the problem ;).

In the cell's subclass:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {

if (!self.isConfigured) {
    CAGradientLayer *bottomFade = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    bottomFade.name = @"Gradient";
    bottomFade.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.background.frame.size.height*0.8, self.background.frame.size.width, self.background.frame.size.height*0.2);
    bottomFade.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    bottomFade.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0);
    bottomFade.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.2f] CGColor], nil];

    [self.background.layer addSublayer:bottomFade];

    self.isConfigured = YES;
    }  

}
```

That does the trick just fine! However, I'm still quite curious about whether there's an easy fix for the problem in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method will be called every time the UICollectionView instance create or reuse a UICollectionViewCell, that's where the problem is.

I don't recommend you use the property like `isConfigured`, the cell should keep a BOOL variable, and will check the property every time `layoutSubviews` been called, its a waste of memory and performance.

As [nferocious76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266278/nferocious76) said, `awakeFromNib:` method, which will be called only once on its life cycle, is the best solution for this case.

By the way, as I can't comment, you should call `[super layoutSubviews]` at the begin of `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions, I'm much obliged!

Comment: I have one more question though - suppose I need to have bits of code that will calculate the best text color for use in the cell - should I use it in the `layoutSubviews` method, or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: The problem is that I need to access somehow the image downloaded in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. I don't know how can I do so in `awakeFromNib:`  method, because I don't know how to obtain the image data from there.